# I got a SOAP Web Service that gives me a hash related exception, but I don't know where to pass a hash code

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

First I must say that I have no experience whatsoever with SOAP web services.

I got the URL to a SOAP web service, and when I imported the service on Visual Studio via the Add Service Reference option, all the classes I thought I would need were created. However when I try to consume the main service, something like `serviceClient.FindCustomer(customerToFind)`, I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.Ex
>   ceptionDetail]: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: O parâmetro
>   hash é obrigatório e não pode ser nulo ou vazio.

Translating the last part: "The parameter hash is mandatory and cannot be null or empty".

When creating the `serviceClient` object I have no overload that allows me to pass a hash code, neither does the `FindCustomer` method allows me to pass a hash code.

I find no reference to a hash code in the App.config file, do I have to add it manually?

Comment: Do "customerToFind" include a hash field, or is the "hash" field the customerToFind?

Comment: @Gusman The customerToFind object doesn't include a hash field, the FindCustomer method takes a CustomerToFind object. No object in the service definition contains a "hash" field, and the ServiceClient object doesn't have any method that takes a hash as a parameter.